# How to programatically call a macro in a different (ie. external) Access database using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to use Access Database1 to call a macro in Access Database2.

The link below describes how to call an external macro in a visio program, but the syntax seems to be a little different with Access.

[How can I call a VBA macro that is defined in a different file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669377/how-can-i-call-a-vba-macro-that-is-defined-in-a-different-file)

Basically, I want to do something like this (from within database 1)

```
AccessDatabase=pathToOtherDatabase.mdb

AccessDatabase.runMacroA
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: You can attach a database as a reference (code window, tools, references) and use the code from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built in Shell command to call your secondary database, and pass it the macro name in the command line switch, this would force your secondary database to execute the desired macro on open. More about Access command line switches can be found here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207