# How to run a macro defined in an MS Access database from another MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a publicly accessible ms access file - Frontend.accdb for which all tables are linked to another  protected ms access database called Data.accdb.  An import job is defined in the data.accdb which brings data into the data.accdb which will be updated to Frontend.accdb when opened.

I want to add this import job in my `frontend.accdb` so that by clicking a button in the frontend.accdb, data.accdb gets refreshed and the tables inside Frontend.accdb is populated with fresh data.

Comment: If the tables are linked to the back end, the data is live almost instantaneous. You need not dabble with refreshing the links.

Comment: paul, The requirement here is different. I have a macro enabled in data.accdb which imports various .csv files to this database. The frontend.accdb tables are all linked to the tables in this data.accdb. End users use the frontend.accdb. Instead of we developers going and refreshing data.accdb manually, I want the users to get the option to refresh( run the macro in data.accdb) the data.accdb through a button in frontend.accdb. so that they get the tables with latest data. Hope I am clear !

Comment: Maybe `DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", "Data.accdb", acMacro, ...` followed by `DoCmd.RunMacro ...`?

Answer (score 0):

If the back-end tables are linked in the front-end, then you should move the macros to the front-end database to operate on the linked tables.

You can use the shell command as discussed here

[How to programatically call a macro in a different (ie. external) Access database using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348090/how-to-programatically-call-a-macro-in-a-different-ie-external-access-databas)

but this is likely to complicate matters with regard to making sure that the macro has run correctly and other error trapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could open the backend database from the frontend and run the macro, using an 'Application' object.

```
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

'Opening backend database
appAccess.Visible = False 'This can only be here once everyone has trusted the 
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "PathtoBackend" & "\data.accdb"

'Time acknowledge the Trust popups if they haven't trusted the db
 Do
    Sleep 1000 'Assumes you have the Win API Sleep command available. 
    DoEvents
Loop While Not appAccess.CurrentProject.IsTrusted

appAccess.Run "Import Data Macro Name"
appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
appAccess.Quit
```

OR

Move the entire table update macro to the front end, and push the data from the source to the frontend, to the linked tables in the backend using `TransferDatabase`.

```
'Bunch of code that builds the DAO or ADO objects from the source data    
Docmd.TransferDatabase acLink, , "PathToBackend" & "\data.accdb", acTable, "FrontEndTableNameContainingSourceData", "BackendTableNameDestination", , )
```